# ionic framework tabs as a child of templates page

Tags: ionic-framework

How to make tabs in ionic framework as a child on a single page. I want create home page , when i fire next button in home page , it will direct to tabs page. Here is the parent of tabs page {tabs page is child of login.html page}, here is login.html page :

```
<ion-view view-title="Login">
  <ion-content >
    <p>
        <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#> Home</a>
    </p>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here is my app.js :

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.services' is found in services.js
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleLightContent();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
  .state('login',{
    url: '/login',
    templateURL: "templates/login.html"
  })

    .state('tab', {
    parent: 'login',
    url: "/tab",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.chats', {
      url: '/chats',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
          controller: 'ChatsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tab.chat-detail', {
      url: '/chats/:chatId',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/chat-detail.html',
          controller: 'ChatDetailCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('tab.account', {
    url: '/account',
    views: {
      'tab-account': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
        controller: 'AccountCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are pretty close. In `login.html` set the href attribute to `/tab`. Make sure that all the templates mentioned in your code exists, otherwise angular will fail. Maybe you could also change url in `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');` to `/login` so the user will see the login page by default when your app opens.